# How do I return an exception in a form of KeyValuePair (For Multilingual support)

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest

I have a REST Service written in c#, and when I throw an HttpResponseException I want it to detail the exception message (concise message written in several different languages) as a keyValuePair and allow the client application to choose what to use according to language requirements.
If keyValuePair is not recommended and anyone has a different suggestion, that'd be great too, I'm simply looking for a way to implement the idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could Implement a custom exception for this. However, the best way is probably throw a normal exception and let the client convert it i.e. always throw exceptions in English and the client can convert it to the language they need.

Comment: probably you should return single translation of error message depending on Accept-Language header of request?

Comment: Or as @SergeyBerezovskiy suggests work out the language of the client and only return it in that language.